# How to manually close an overlay?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using [NextUI Popover](https://nextui.org/docs/components/popover#custom-content) component and I want to manually close the Popover with a cancel button. I can open and close it with `isOpen` prop but the main problem is that I have it in a map loop, when I open one all the other opens. How can I solve this?

[image]

Popover JSX

```
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

{snipsData.map((snip, index) => (
 <div key={index} className="hoverable-item flex gap-2">

  //....

  <Popover placement="top" isOpen={isOpen} onOpenChange={setIsOpen}>
  //Pop.Trigger Button sets isOpen to true 
    <Popover.Trigger>
      <Button auto light>
        <DeleteDocumentIcon
          fill="#F31260"
          className="cursor-pointer"
          width={26}
          height={26}
        />
      </Button>
    </Popover.Trigger>
    <Popover.Content>
      <DeleteUser
        snip={snip}
        handleDelete={handleDelete}
        setIsOpen={setIsOpen}
      />
    </Popover.Content>
  </Popover>
 </div>
))}
```

Overlay buttons in `<DeleteUser />`

```
<Grid>
  <Button size="sm" light onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}>
    Cancel
  </Button>
</Grid>
<Grid>
  <Button
    size="sm"
    shadow
    color="error"
    onClick={() => handleDelete(snip.id)}
  >
    Delete
  </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you include a more complete example? I generally know what you mean by having it in a loop, but it would be useful to see your attempt using `isOpen` so we can build from that.

Comment: Thank you. Where is the map loop you referenced?

Comment: It's much longer code but I have now added the map loop.

Comment: It was an important piece in giving a helpful answer, I needed to see what you were working with. I've posted an answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the problem is that you're using a binary state (`isOpen`) to represent something with more than binary state-- namely, the `isOpen` state of every snip.

There are a few ways to do this, but I personally like having the state be an object containing a mapping from `index => boolean`

```
const [allOpenStates, setAllOpenStates] = useState({});
// in this case, we'll have an object that maps from an
// index to a boolean
// the default state is closed, so a missing value in the map
// will get interpreted as false

{snipsData.map((snip, index) => (
 <div key={index} className="hoverable-item flex gap-2">

  //....

  <Popover placement="top" 
       isOpen={allOpenStates[index]} // it will be undefined if it hasn't ever been opened, which is fine, since undefined is falsey
       onOpenChange={nowOpen => setAllOpenStates(oldState => {...oldState, [index]: nowOpen} )}>

  //Pop.Trigger Button sets allOpenStates[index] = true
    <Popover.Trigger>
      <Button auto light>
        <DeleteDocumentIcon
          fill="#F31260"
          className="cursor-pointer"
          width={26}
          height={26}
        />
      </Button>
    </Popover.Trigger>
    <Popover.Content>
      <DeleteUser
        snip={snip}
        handleDelete={handleDelete}
        setIsOpen={setIsOpen}
      />
    </Popover.Content>
  </Popover>
 </div>
))}
```

I'm doing this without trying it myself, so some of the syntax may be off. But the general idea is that you need to keep track of the open state for each index, and use that individual index's state for determining if the popover is open and how to handle open/close events.

Another solution would be using a Set of numbers (the index values), where Set membership indicates that the popover is open. Opening the popover would add that index to the set, and closing would remove from the set.This would require some ugly code though, since set operations are mutating.

Comment: Thanks! Thats worked for opening, but how can I close it with the cancel button with onClick?

Comment: Np! Clicking outside the popover will trigger `onOpenChange` (with an argument of `false`). Read through the code there and try to dissect it. If you want to create a button that manually will close the popover, you can use the same logic, but always set the index to false. `<Button onClick={() => setAllOpenStates(oldState => {...oldState, [index]: false} )}}> Close popover for snip #{index} </Button>`

Comment: Look carefully at what's happening. I'm essentially just declaring that now `allOpenStates[index] = false`, setting this particular snip (by its index) to closed, but the way to actually chance that state is through `setAllOpenStates(...)`.

Comment: Happy to help! Using `useState` properly takes some getting used to, but it's really powerful (and honestly pretty intuitive) after you get used to it. Happy programming :)

Comment: Yeah, looking at the code it's readable and it's working and still doesn't make much sense to me. It's something I'll have to look deeper into and understand it. Thanks and you too.

Comment: @Mintee btw, I actually just integrated the Next UI Popover into my project because of your post! I'm mainly using `MUI`, but I liked the animation and placement effects of the `Next UI` one, so I adopted it. I actually had a question about my own implementation, that I referred back to your question to answer for myself :P

Comment: @Mintee I'd recommend getting the React browser dev tools extension, and looking at the state for your component in real-time as you open and close popovers, it might make it click a bit more.

Comment: I actually have it but almost never use it, maybe now it's the time to start using it more often. And glad I could help 